# How to pass [object Object] to a JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, tcl

This is the scenario. There is a pre-existing drag-drop functionality we use and I m extending the same for use in a different case.

(1) Lots of local variable are built up in the dragdrop.js file and the context is ***this*** (this.dragId etc.).

(2) I'm using a modal to bring up a list of checkboxes. The user selects the data he wants to and clicks Save.

(3) I call saveAttribute() and use JQuery to get the checked values. However, without the context, I cannot proceed to work on this project.

```
Without passing *this*, I don't have a context. 
If I try to pass *this* in the first call from JS to a tcl file and then back 
to a JS function, it expects JS to read [object Object]. I m not sure how to do this. 
Any help is appreciated.
```

The **this.toSource()** before passing to the tcl file, looks like this

```
({m_pageWrap:{}, m_parentDragSite:{m_pageWrap:{}, m_parentDragSite:null, m_CanHaveChildSites:true, m_groups:[{}, {}], m_allDraggableBoxes:[{m_box:{}, childSite:{m_pageWrap:{}, m_parentDragSite:{}, m_CanHaveChildSites:false, m_groups:[], m_allDraggableBoxes:[{m_box:{}, childSite:null, m_dragSite:{}, m_handle:null, m_coord:{x:0, y:0}, m_handleCoord:{x:0, y:0}, m_handlePositionStale:true, m_positionStale:true, m_cachePosition:true, m_isBeingEdited:false, m_BoxHandleClone:null, m_dragHandleObj:{m_handle:null, m_BoxHandleClone:null, m_isBeingEdited:false, m_OwningDraggableBox:null, m_saveButton:null}, m_commandHandle:null, m_removeCommandHandle:null, m_insertCommandHandle:null, m_reuseables:[], m_commands:[], m_isBeingCreated:false, m_isDummy:true, m_heightToExclude:0, m_saveDeleteIfno:false, m_canBeDropTarget:false}], m_draggedBoxIndex:-1, m_OrigBoxPos:{x:0, y:0}, m_InitialMousePos:{x:0, y:0}, m_Mousediff:{x:0, y:0}, m_CurrentMousePos:{x:0, y:0}, m_BoxClone:null, m_DragPositiveDirection:true, m_Dragging:false, threshold:2, m_Released:false, m_DraggedObject:null, m_DummyBox:{}, m_defaultBoxID:null, m_boxCloneY:0, m_allReuseables:[], m_drag_events:[], m_EventListenerFuncName:"addEventListener", m_EventListenerFuncPrefix:"", m_isDraggableWithinSite:false, m_isDroppableWithinSite:false, m_ignoreSiteHasDroppables:true, m_parentOfBox:{}}, m_dragSite:{}, m_handle:null, m_coord:{x:0, y:0}, m_handleCoord:{x:0, y:0}, m_handlePositionStale:true, m_positionStale:true, m_cachePosition:true, m_isBeingEdited:false, m_BoxHandleClone:null, m_dragHandleObj:{m_handle:null, m_BoxHandleClone:null, m_isBeingEdited:false, m_OwningDraggableBox:null, m_saveButton:null}, m_commandHandle:null, m_removeCommandHandle:null, m_insertCommandHandle:{}, m_reuseables:[], m_commands:[], m_isBeingCreated:false, m_isDummy:false, m_heightToExclude:0, m_saveDeleteIfno:false, m_canBeDropTarget:true}, {m_box:{}, childSite:{}, m_dragSite:{}, m_handle:{}, m_coord:{x:0, y:0}, m_handleCoord:{x:515, y:524}, m_handlePositionStale:true, m_positionStale:true, m_cachePosition:true, m_isBeingEdited:false, m_BoxHandleClone:{}, m_dragHandleObj:{m_handle:{}, m_BoxHandleClone:null, m_isBeingEdited:false, m_OwningDraggableBox:{}, m_saveButton:null}, m_commandHandle:{}, m_removeCommandHandle:{}, m_insertCommandHandle:{}, m_reuseables:[], m_commands:[[{}, "onclick", (function (){return _b3[_b4].apply(_b3,arguments||[]);}), 1], [{}, "onclick", (function (){return _b3[_b4].apply(_b3,arguments||[]);}), 1]], m_isBeingCreated:false, m_isDummy:false, m_heightToExclude:0, m_saveDeleteIfno:false, m_canBeDropTarget:true}], m_draggedBoxIndex:-1, m_OrigBoxPos:{x:0, y:0}, m_InitialMousePos:{x:0, y:0}, m_Mousediff:{x:0, y:0}, m_CurrentMousePos:{x:0, y:0}, m_BoxClone:null, m_DragPositiveDirection:true, m_Dragging:false, threshold:2, m_Released:false, m_DraggedObject:null, m_DummyBox:null, m_defaultBoxID:null, m_boxCloneY:0, m_allReuseables:[], m_drag_events:[], m_EventListenerFuncName:"addEventListener", m_EventListenerFuncPrefix:"", m_isDraggableWithinSite:true, m_isDroppableWithinSite:true, m_ignoreSiteHasDroppables:false, m_parentOfBox:{}, m_formName:"TemplateEditForm"}, m_CanHaveChildSites:false, m_groups:[], m_allDraggableBoxes:[{m_box:{}, childSite:null, m_dragSite:{}, m_handle:null, m_coord:{x:0, y:0}, m_handleCoord:{x:0, y:0}, m_handlePositionStale:true, m_positionStale:true, m_cachePosition:true, m_isBeingEdited:false, m_BoxHandleClone:null, m_dragHandleObj:{m_handle:null, m_BoxHandleClone:null, m_isBeingEdited:false, m_OwningDraggableBox:null, m_saveButton:null}, m_commandHandle:null, m_removeCommandHandle:null, m_insertCommandHandle:null, m_reuseables:[], m_commands:[], m_isBeingCreated:false, m_isDummy:true, m_heightToExclude:0, m_saveDeleteIfno:false, m_canBeDropTarget:true}], m_draggedBoxIndex:-1, m_OrigBoxPos:{x:0, y:0}, m_InitialMousePos:{x:0, y:0}, m_Mousediff:{x:0, y:0}, m_CurrentMousePos:{x:0, y:0}, m_BoxClone:null, m_DragPositiveDirection:true, m_Dragging:false, threshold:2, m_Released:false, m_DraggedObject:null, m_DummyBox:{}, m_defaultBoxID:null, m_boxCloneY:0, m_allReuseables:[], m_drag_events:[], m_EventListenerFuncName:"addEventListener", m_EventListenerFuncPrefix:"", m_isDraggableWithinSite:true, m_isDroppableWithinSite:true, m_ignoreSiteHasDroppables:true, m_parentOfBox:{}})
```

First step: JS Code:

```
a.b.addAttribute = function()
{
try {
    alert(this.toSource()); // You can see the output of this above.
    return modalCheck('/acct/modal-list-attributes?');
    alert("here");
   } catch(err) {       
  }
};
```

Second Step (the context is now [object Object] and this is in tcl file - the modal that pops up with checkboxes.):

```
 <input type=\"button\" value=\"[local_string save_text $user_id]\" onclick=\"saveAttribute($context)\" id=\"saveAttr\" class=\"BTNAction\"/> class=\"BTNAction\"/>
```

This step - I need help to pass the [object Object] to a JS function called from onclick in submit button.

```
function saveAttribute(object) {
  alert(object.toSource());
  //some operations to do with help of context.
}
```

Thanks,

Anand

Comment: You must provide code and more context..

Comment: I have edited, to provide more information. The help I need is to read [object Object] in the third step- JS function that would essentially have access to all information seen in this.toSource();. Would appreciate your input. Thanks!

Comment: Please be aware that `toSource` is only supported in Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource.

Comment: Yes and I have it only to check what the object contains.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see values from objects/variables you shouldn't use `alert`
Make use of `console.log(object);` or `console.info(object);` or console.debug(object);`

This will print values on your browser developer console, which you can get by F12

Comment: I m aware of that. Firefox provides an alternative. MY question is not specific to your answer. I m looking for a way to pass and read [object Object] in a JS function. how to define the JS function? should it be function saveAttribute ([object Object]) ?

Answer (score 0):

seems like classic javascript this-problem.

how are you populating your checkboxes list? do you use some kind of ajax for that?

Comment: Well. The modal page handles that. We have a query fetching mechanism and a proc that will convert it into checkboxes using the data set.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to be *very* clear about what is interpreting a piece of code. Is it the client-side Javascript? Is it the server-side Tcl? Without that clarity, you'll get in a total mess!

The simplest thing is to put as much of the JS as possible in a static file that you can just serve up statically; the hosting environment will do that just fine if you tell it to. Then you just need to generate the minimal bits of dynamic JS in the Tcl to tie the pieces together; that's much simpler, especially as you can use simple rules-of-thumb to detect hazards. For example, you can say that there should be no Tcl command substitutions used directly to create JS, meaning that you can then check for `[`…`]` and add in backslashes without having to think about it much. (Square brackets have the downside of meaning something to both languages. `$` is also possibly problematic if you're using jQuery, as that's also a Tcl metasyntax character *when followed by a letter or parenthesis*. Multi-language work can suck.)

The JS `this` can't pass to the server and back; it's non-trivial to serialize (and going over any network connection forces some serialization). Passing the name of an object that you then use to look up the `this` is quite possible though, but you don't usually need that sort of complexity.

If you've got a `this`-like concept on the Tcl side, that (probably) *can* be transferred to the client and back (i.e., as long as the session context is maintained) as Tcl values are always serializable. (The non-serializable parts stay bound to the context, the “interpreter”.) If you're doing this, it's probably easiest to put the value in a variable and substitute that; even if it isn't technically required, it may be clearer.

---

Your code samples are too confusing for me to figure out some examples for you to try that are recognisably similar. (Who is handling the `[object Object]` anyway? What framework are you using? It's a legal Tcl command substitution… but I don't know exactly what you want to do with it; I've not enough information to work out its semantics…)